# How to create a differencing VHD using CreateVirtualDisk in Windows 2008 R2

Tags: c++, windows, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, vhd

I'm trying to create a differencing VHD using CreateVirtualDisk API. MSDN examples

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Virtual-hard-disk-03108ed3

is supported only on Win 8/2012. But, if i try the same on Win 2008 R2, CREATE_VIRTUAL_DISK_VERSION_2 is not available. Tried using CREATE_VIRTUAL_DISK_VERSION_1 with corresponding values (Specifying parent VHD) CreateVirtualDisk fails with error code 87.

I tried creating a new VHD (not a differencing) it is getting created.

How to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Use CreateVirtualDisk with out passing the any sizes, but pass only the parent VHD path. All the parameters which we have not passed will be taken from parent VHD.

CREATE_VIRTUAL_DISK_VERSION_2  is available online in Win 8/2012